# getting byte[] (or char[]) from maskedTextBox

Tags: c#

I want to get text inputted by the user into the maskedTextBox and then encode it into byte[] which will be hashed into SHA256 to compare with password hashes stored at my database. The problem is that I've only found .GetCharFromPosition(Point pt) which I don't know how to use (I would know if it would be a simple index in place of this "Point") and .GetHashCode but it needs to be SHA256, not some undefined hash...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the bytes of a string in a certain encoding using [`Encoding.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ds4kkd55.aspx). For example, to get it as an array of bytes as UTF-8:

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourTextBox.Text)
```

Comment: that was my first thought but there is written "gets or sets the text as it is _currently displayed_ to the user" which is "###" or something similar in case of maskedTextBox.

Comment: @SzymonM.Sabat: Just try it. Anyway, is this a password field? If it is, use a regular `TextBox` and set `UseSystemPasswordChar` to `true`.